# Undefined symbols for architecture: *Extension where Self : Protocol* referenced from: protocol witness for *protocol.func*

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

In Framework1 I have the following code:

```
public protocol SomeProtocol{
    func doSomething()
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self : UIButton{
    public func doSomething(){}
}
```

In Framework2, which imports Framework1 as a Cocoa pod, I add conformance to SomeProtocol like this

```
extension UIButton : SomeProtocol{}
```

Framework1 builds successfully, however, I receive the following Apple Mach-O Linker Error when building Framework2:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "(extension in
>   Framework1): Framework1.SomeProtocol.doSomething () -> ()", referenced from:
>         protocol witness for Framework1.SomeProtocol.doSomething () -> () in conformance __ObjC.UIButton : Framework1.SomeProtocol in
>   Framework2 in SomeFile.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

If I move the protocol conformance of UIButton into Framework1 file as such:

```
public protocol SomeProtocol{
    func doSomething()
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self : UIButton{
    public func doSomething(){}
}

extension UIButton : SomeProtocol{}
```

Framework1 will successfully build. This does not work for me though because I need to establish UIButton's conformance to SomeProtocol in Framework2 and not Framework1.

My current solution is simply to remove

```
extension SomeProtocol where Self : UIButton{
    public func doSomething(){}
}
```

from Framework1 and implement it in the UIButton extension in Framework2 like this:

```
extension UIButton : SomeProtocol{
    public func doSomething(){}
}
```

This, however, is not a good solution because I would like to be able to have this implementation of doSomething for a UIButton shared between any framework consuming Framework1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try making your extension public

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: As a last resort, try making your extension `open`...

Comment: I do not think extensions can be made open.

Comment: Swift doesn't know a class, for which this extension implementation should be added when builds framework1. You can simply add extension UIButton : SomeProtocol to framework1 and it will be shared for all framework1 consumers.

Comment: This would work, but I need my extension to be defined in Framework 2 not 1.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem.